# JQuery and z-index

Tags: jquery, z-index

I have two DIVs:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

In special cases **div2** takes z-index:999. And in that case I can't to catch click on **div1**. Defined jquery funciton:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
    $j(document).click( function(e) {
        var clicked = $j(e.target);
    })
})
```

So, scenarion is follows:

- $j(document).click function called if click occurs on any div with the same z-index
- $j(document).click function called if click occurs on div with the **greater** z-index and doesn't called on click on another

Are there any ways to handle all clicks made on the whole screen?

Comment: If the `<div>` elements overlap, you won't be able to click through the element on top. There are some workarounds, like the `pointer-events:none` CSS, or jQuery `.trigger()` method.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/fueQj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make sure to handle every clicks over any divs of any depth, you can validate that the mouse is over while clicking in the document then trigger the click event of that div. What about :

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    $('div').each(function(){
        if (e.pageX >= $(this).position.left &&
            e.pageX <= $(this).position.left+$(this).width() &&
            e.pageY >= $(this).position.top &&
            e.pageY <= $(this).position.top+$(this).height()
         ){
            $(this).trigger('click');
         }
    });
});
```

This is an overkill solution but it may work.. hope this help.